# How to install OS through Pendrive

Tags: operating-system

I had tried lot of methods to install Operating System in laptop..But isn't working..Could you  please any one can suggest the easiest way for doing this..Thanks...?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what operating systems you're talking about but:

Unetbootin works wonders for linux distros (most of the time). It sets up a bootable live USB drive. Just choose a distro from a list or point to an ISO and you're good to go (you'll need an USB drive with at least 1gb).

Read more [here](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I need to install windows 7 OS ( I am having windows 7 CD)

Comment: @Jahoor If you have a CD, then we can't help you if all we know is: "But isn't working"...